How can I be sure my current employer won't be told about my background check?
I worked for A, then B, then A again. A was closed, and now I work for C (my current employer was one of the owners of A).
Now, I heard they can do background checks without notifying me first. If they don't call my current employer, they may try to call A and then end up letting C know. How to handle this situation?
Edit: To clarify, my current employer is C, a owner of A. I want to search for another job. How can I make sure a future background check from company D won't call my current employer?

So to make sure I am understanding this question correctly.  Your employment goes: A -> B -> A -> C.  Now you are looking to apply to companies D1 through D20 and do not want D1 through D20 to do something that will cause C to find out that you are looking for a new job?

Background check on what and for what purpose? What are you worried about ? What do you local labor law say about background checks (many of those are perfectly legal in many countries).

@Anketam pretty much yes. I tried to edit the question with more info

@UzyOma, Where are you located, because this would completely depend on the jurisdiction you're in. For instance in California, they require your permission for a background check.

If A is closed, how can they call A, I presume A was not on your resume? Employers don't typically just randomly do background checks on employees unless they have a reason.  They are not free. They can only perform a background check based on the information you provide them.  Just having a name isn't enough information, if you are giving out more than a name at the interview stage, you are giving out too much PII.

Frame challenge: In many companies, internal moves are very normal as people seek new challenges and opportunities. If you're is one of these, your current management may even assist you. ((I should have done that more often during my own career.)

If you have concerns that Company C will retaliate against you for seeking another job, then the first thing you need to do is: document everything.  You want to have a solid paper trail (that is not saved on hardware that the company controls) that you have been a model employee with good reviews.  This will only protect you from certain forms of retaliation, but it is better to have it and not need it (or not useful) than the reverse.
Bad news is that there is nothing you can do to stop someone or a company that is conducting a background check from contacting someone you do not want them to contact.  I have had friends and colleagues ask not to contact X, and that was the very first person they contacted.
Good news is that background checks are not cheap quick things, so companies typically will only conduct them after they have interviewed you and are preparing an offer.  Interviews are two way streets so your best defense is if a company you are interviewing with does not meet your standards, let them know that you do not think you would be a good fit for their company.  That will (normally) kill the process before they get to the step they would conduct a background check.
Meanwhile if you find Company D that is amazing and the interview goes well and they do conduct the background check and contact Company C, and said individual reacts poorly to this, at least you have your next job lined up.  And if Company C bad mouths you to Company D to the point they rescind the job offer well you now have a case to sue Company C, after all you did document that you were model employee... right?

It is not unusual to have a pre-offer background check avoid tipping off your current employer. What you are asking for is a little more tricky because you feel that the check regarding company A will tip off company C.
It does depend on the reason for the check, and what they have to tell the previous company.
If they want to prove employment dates, they might accept tax forms or pay-stubs. If they want to know your title that might be ok if they don't have to explain why. If they want to talk to a manager or a co-worker that is much hard to disguise.
Some companies might not be comfortable being unable to verify your employment history for the majority of the years they are interested in. Of course if you had only one employer in the last decade they would be in a similar position.
Depending on where you live, and where the job is, national or local laws might define what types of checks they can do, and what notice they need to give you and the employer. When the subject comes up, explain your concern, and see how they react. Review all the paperwork.

It is quite common to request our new to-be employer not to contact your current employer.  As an employer, I have always honoured that request.
Another way is to not list your current employment in your resume.
Otherwise, a routine search is unlikely to discover where you have worked (in the past), unless you have made public or social media posts about it.

It seems like there is information missing from the OP. For example, why would they do a background check once you've been hired?
There is little or nothing that you can do.
Depending on the country there might be privacy laws, but a company that does the checks should already know what is acceptable.

Ok, let me clear some misinformation's. I worked for A. Now for C. The owner of C was one of the owners of A. I want to find another job. If a company D tries to do a background check on me, how can I make sure my current company doesn't find out about the background check?

@UzyOma - Be honest with company D and tell them that you don't want them to contact company C. Be clear with company D why. Offer proof of employment.
